# What type of phrase is "The sinking of the Titanic led to..."?

Tags: phrases

In the sentence, "The sinking of the Titanic led to increased safety standards", is The sinking of the Titanic a gerund phrase?  If not, what is it?

Comment: I'd call that a gerund. When verbs work as nouns, you could try "the horror of the Titanic" or "the disaster of the Titanic ."

Comment: No, it's not a gerund. Gerunds are verbs and can't take definite articles. _The Titanic's sinking_ would be a gerund, though it could also just be a noun -- in this sentence you can't tell. What _the sinking of the Titanic_ is is a noun phrase; it's the nominalization of either the transitive clause _[`Indefinite`] sank the Titanic_ or the intransitive one _the Titanic sank_. Nominalizations or other compacting strategies always lose information and therefore increase ambiguity.

Comment: I'd call the ing-form 'an ing-form somewhere near half way along the noun-verb ing-form continuum'.  Also note that this 'sinking' is ambiguous; does it relate to ergative 'The Titanic sank' or active 'The collision with the iceberg [along with umpteen other factors] sank the Titanic'? cf 'the embarrassing sinking of the _SS Principessa Jolanda_, on launching' vs 'the Royal Navy's sinking of the _Bismarck_'.

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler commented:

> No, it's not a gerund. Gerunds are verbs and can't take definite articles. *The Titanic's sinking* would be a gerund, though it could also just be a noun -- in this sentence you can't tell. What *the sinking of the Titanic* is is a noun phrase; it's the nominalization of either the transitive clause *[Indefinite] sank the Titanic* or the intransitive one *the Titanic sank.* Nominalizations or other compacting strategies always lose information and therefore increase ambiguity.